# Is their a toggl command line interface

Tags: command-line

I am looking for an application to handle toggl (https://www.toggl.com/track#) commands. For instance one could write a bash script that starts and/or stops a task in toggl.

Searching the web didn't result in any package... Is their a package/repository available?

A use case: I work on a project so I write a script that first starts the project on toggle, then the IDE is started. When the user closes the IDE, the script is activated again and the task is turned of on toggl.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what is your use case?

Comment: See modified question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the toggl API ([API documentation on github](https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs)). Using it and `curl` allows for bash scripts doing basically anything toggl is capable of, see the examples in the chapters of the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial command line interface for Toggl here:
https://github.com/drobertadams/toggl-cli